# Get position in table with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have table Players with columns: ID Name Points

What is most efficient way to get player position ordered by points using LINQ?

Comment: are you able to obtain the result set ordered by Point? after that, are you asking how to get the ordinal of a record for which you know the ID ?

Comment: db.Players.OrderByDescending(u =>u.Points).ToList(); Where db is the linq data context

Comment: do you mean the position in the list of where the table is?  Or do you mean ID=position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any solution will require at least one iteration through all elements, but the following will suffice:

```
var ordered = players.OrderByDescending(p => p.Points).ToList();
```

This will order the elements in one pass and then store the result in a list to preserve the ordering without need to 'order' again:

```
int position = ordered.IndexOf(player);
```

Answer (score 2):

your demande is a single linq query but this is a way to do it:

```
int pos = 0;

foreach(var item in Players.OrderByDescending(u =>u.Points).ToList())
{
  pos++;
  if (item.Name == yourPlayerName)
  break;
} 
return pos;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option to get the position (that's similar to Akrem's but doesn't iterate the collection manually).

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        var table = new[] 
        {
            new{ Id = 1, Name = "Paul", Points = 10},
            new{ Id = 2, Name = "Ringo", Points = 2},
            new{ Id = 3, Name = "George", Points = 30},
            new{ Id = 4, Name = "John", Points = 5}
        };
        int position = table.OrderByDescending(x => x.Points).TakeWhile(x => x.Name != "Paul").Count() + 1;
        Assert.AreEqual(2, position);
    }
```